# Overriding controls from another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, inheritance, devexpress

I've got an app that I need a bit of help with.  It uses DevExpress controls (C#, vs2012) and I'm having a bit of difficulty getting a User Control to override the events from the main form. The `MainForm` inherits from DevExpress's `RibbonForm` and is laid out in the typical Outlook fashion, with the Ribbon at the top, NavBar on the left side, and Content area on the right.  As you can see from my diagram, I currently have the `MainForm` and then several UserControls that I load into a `Panel` control when a specific nav bar button is clicked.  So when the user clicks 'Customers', the `Customer` usercontrol is loaded in the content area.  What I'm trying to do now is in each UserControl, override the Ribbon events from the `MainForm` so I can have the logic in each UserControl.  For instance, in Customers, the `Save` ribbon event would do something different than the `Orders` `Save` event.
[image]

If I have the UserControls inherit from the `MainForm`, then they will each have the ribbon and navbar items on them, which I don't want.  Is there any way to get the UserControls to override the ribbon events from the `MainForm` form?

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the UserControls to override the ribbon events
>   from the MainForm form?

Yes. This way is [Ribbon Merging](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3451).
Just add the RibbonControl into each user control. Add and customize all needed commands in each case. Then use the [RibbonControl.MergeRibbon](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_MergeRibbontopic)/[RibbonControl.UnmergeRibbon](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_UnMergeRibbontopic) methods when switching between these user controls - child ribbon will be merged/unmerged into/form parent ribbon.